Printing an array through a loop outputs more elements than it has
A teacher had this specific program as an example in one of his PowerPoints, and I don't understand why (as he claims) it is wrong:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i, pin[3], arr[3];

    pin[0] = 20;

    for( i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = 100;
        printf("%d\n",arr[i]);
    }
    printf("%d\n",pin[0]);
    return 0;
}

It outputs "100", 5 times, and I don't get why that happens.

"How to debug small programs"

What do you think it should print out?

There is no explanation. the array arr can hold 3 values (at arr[0], arr[1], and arr[2]); you attemp to write to the non-existing arr[3] invoking UB (Undefined Behaviour).

others have pointed out the issue in the code, but it prints out 5 100s because the loop is looping 5 times, each printing out the 100 which was just assigned

@J.Doe The loop runs only 4 times. But there is another print after the loop.

"I don't get why that happens.", perhaps this could help you get why that happens: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239938/accessing-an-array-out-of-bounds-gives-no-error-why

The short answer: The code is "wrong" because there is an out-of-bounds array access.
More details:
The loop:
for( i=0; i<4; i++)
{
    arr[i] = 100;
    printf("%d\n",arr[i]);
}

can be unrolled to:
arr[0] = 100;
printf("%d\n",arr[0]);
arr[1] = 100;
printf("%d\n",arr[1]);
arr[2] = 100;
printf("%d\n",arr[2]);
arr[3] = 100;
printf("%d\n",arr[3]);

However you have
int ...., arr[3];

so arr has only 3 elements and the allowed access is arr[0], arr[1], arr[2]
But the unrolled code has:
arr[3] = 100;
printf("%d\n",arr[3]);

This access to arr[3] is out-of-bounds (i.e. outside the valid array range)  and the program has undefined behavior. This means that nothing in the C standard tells what the result shall be.
BTW:
You write:

It gives me x5 "100"s

Well, it can't be explained in general (as the behavior is undefined). On your system it's likely that arr[3] = 100 changed pin[0] from 20 to 100... but that's just a "wild guess". Other systems may give other results.
